# Ggplot visualization improve

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I have a data frame from a Bici service, it looks like this, where **Origen_Id** is the station's number, and **Num_Viaje_Ori** is the total number of trips that start in that station.

| Origen_Id | Num_F | Num_M | Num_Viaje_Ori | Destino_Id | Num_F_d | Num_M_d | Num_Viaje_Des |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 1616 | 3973 | 5589 | 11 | 139 | 5 3855 | 5250 |
| 34 | 962 | 3232 | 4194 | 34 | 1340 | 4236 | 5576 |
| 35 | 1321 | 3993 | 5314 | 35 | 1418 | 4239 | 5657 |
| 50 | 1797 | 4293 | 6090 | 50 | 1785 | 4314 | 6099 |
| 51 | 1891 | 5186 | 7077 | 51 | 3084 | 7771 | 10855 |
| 52 | 1379 | 4320 | 5699 | 52 | 1299 | 3913 | 5212 |
| 54 | 1275 | 3950 | 5225 | 54 | 1373 | 4046 | 5419 |
| 75 | 1332 | 2939 | 4271 | 75 | 1202 | 2763 | 3965 |
| 194 | 1346 | 3792 | 5138 | 194 | 632 | 1845 | 2477 |
| 271 | 1511 | 3640 | 5151 | 271 | 1483 | 3750 | 5233 |

When I run

```
s<-ggplot(most, aes(x=Origen_Id, y=Num_Viaje_Ori))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

I got

[image]

How can I fix it?, I mean, how can I make the bars got closer?

Comment: Since orgenid is not a continuous number you can convert it to a character or factor and make a column chart

Comment: In this case it looks like `Origen_Id` is effectively a name for a station, but it's stored in R as a numeric value and so ggplot2 is interpreting it as a quantity. If you add `most$Origen_Id = as.character(most$Origen_Id)` before your `ggplot` call, that will change it to character data so that your categories are treated as discrete items.

Comment: What the others said. And unrelated: save yourself some typing with `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing the commented suggestions, you should get:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tibble)
library(ggthemes)

most <- 
  tibble::tribble(
  ~Origen_Id, ~Num_F, ~Num_M, ~Num_Viaje_Ori, ~Destino_Id, ~Num_F_d, ~Num_M_d, ~Num_Viaje_Des,
         11L,  1616L,  3973L,          5589L,         11L,     139L, "5 3855",          5250L,
         34L,   962L,  3232L,          4194L,         34L,    1340L,   "4236",          5576L,
         35L,  1321L,  3993L,          5314L,         35L,    1418L,   "4239",          5657L,
         50L,  1797L,  4293L,          6090L,         50L,    1785L,   "4314",          6099L,
         51L,  1891L,  5186L,          7077L,         51L,    3084L,   "7771",         10855L,
         52L,  1379L,  4320L,          5699L,         52L,    1299L,   "3913",          5212L,
         54L,  1275L,  3950L,          5225L,         54L,    1373L,   "4046",          5419L,
         75L,  1332L,  2939L,          4271L,         75L,    1202L,   "2763",          3965L,
        194L,  1346L,  3792L,          5138L,        194L,     632L,   "1845",          2477L,
        271L,  1511L,  3640L,          5151L,        271L,    1483L,   "3750",          5233L
  )

most %>% 
  mutate(Origen_Id = as.factor(Origen_Id)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Origen_Id, y=Num_Viaje_Ori)) +
  geom_col(fill = "darkslateblue") + 
  ggthemes::theme_economist_white()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>